# Should dry salami develop green mould?

Tags: food-safety, storage-lifetime, storage, salami

I recently (5 weeks ago), purchased a set of dry salami from a food festival. I kept them in the plastic bag that they came in; however, when I recently checked them, they were completely covered with furry-looking green mould.

My understanding of dry salami is that it is supposed to be able to be kept for (in some cases) several years without risk. So I am confused, What could have caused the mould growth that I experienced?

Comment: They can be kept for long times, but only if they're kept dry -- the plastic might've held in moisture.

Answer (score 5):

Take the salamis out of the bag.

Are they complete sausages or has it been sliced? Whole sausages should not be kept in a plastic bag without desiccants even if it's just a ball of paper towels.

Sliced salamis shouldn't be kept for more than a couple weeks.

If they are whole, don't be fooled that you can just wash the skin, molds grow tendrils into its food, not unlike roots, so don't risk it.

Comment: Although there are some dry salamis where there's specifically a white mold that develops ... in that case, you can either just slice and eat it, or peel the casing off (and the mold with it) before slicing.  It's the green/purple/black/fuzzy molds that are a problem.